# Rails : Where is the best place to put rspec files for modules in lib directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, module

I am developing ruby modules in rails `lib/` directory. But I don't know where to put rspec files for them.

`spec/lib/` directory doesn't seem to be the best place.

```
'app/controller' -> 'spec/controllers'
'app/models'     -> 'spec/models'
'app/views'      -> 'spec/views' 
'lib/'           -> '??(my question)'
```

Is there any best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a best practice, but you can see at popular Rails projects like [Diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/tree/develop/spec) and [Discource](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/tree/master/spec) they use `spec/lib` and `spec/components` folders. So, I guess this practice is good enough.